# speakhere sample can not work correctly when I redefine the time interval of callback function

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, core-audio, avaudioplayer

I downloaded the speakHere example and changed the parameters liked below:

```
#define kBufferDurationSeconds  0.020

void AQRecorder::SetupAudioFormat(UInt32 inFormatID)
{
   memset(&mRecordFormat,0, sizeof(mRecordFormat));
   mRecordFormat.mFormatID =kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
   mRecordFormat.mSampleRate =8000.0; 
   mRecordFormat.mFormatFlags =kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;
   mRecordFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
   mRecordFormat.mFramesPerPacket  = mRecordFormat.mChannelsPerFrame =1;
   mRecordFormat.mBytesPerFrame = (mRecordFormat.mBitsPerChannel/8) *      mRecordFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
   mRecordFormat.mBytesPerPacket = mRecordFormat.mBytesPerFrame ;
}
```

But I found that it seemed the time interval of the callback function `AQRecorder::MyInputBufferHandler()` was called but not per 20ms. It called the callback function four times with 1ms interval and after 500ms calls the callback function one time, then four times with 1ms, then 500ms,over and over again. But I set the parameter `kBufferDurationSeconds = 0.02`
what cause this problem. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS, the Audio Session setPreferredIOBufferDuration API (did you even use an OS buffer duration call?) is only a request regarding the app's preference.    The OS is free to choose a buffer duration different, but compatible with what iOS thinks is best (for battery life, compatibility with other apps, etc.)

Audio Queues run on top of Audio Units.  If the RemoteIO Audio Unit is using 500 mS buffers, it will cut them up into 4 smaller Audio Queue buffers and pass those smaller buffers to the Audio Queue API in a quick burst.

If you use the Audio Unit API instead of the Audio Queue API, and the Audio Session API for a setPreferredIOBufferDuration message, you may be able to request and get shorter, more evenly spaced, audio buffers.